# How to programmatically change rendered attribute of a p:column in p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In my facelets xhtml-view I have a primefaces dataTable where I hide and show columns dynamically with a self made columnToggler-composite.

My first implemention works fine and uses explicit rendered-attributes for all configurable columns that are bound to a serverside columModel ...

```
<p:dataTable id="myDataTable" ...>
  <p:column rendered="#{bean.myColumnModel.isVisible('A Column name')}" >
    ...
  </p:column>
  <!-- many other columns -->
</p:dataTable>

<my:columnToggler columnModel="#{bean.myColumnModel}" for="myDataTable" />
```

I want to get rid of these rendered-attributes, because I already know which columns are configurable. Here is how I change the dataTable at runtime:

```
private void renderColumnsInDataTable() {

    List columns = dataTable.getColumns();

    for (Iterator<Column> iterator = columns.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

        ...

        if (isColumnConfigurable(columnName)) {

          column.setRendered(isVisible(columnName));

        }
    }
```

This works except that I have a problem with the first invocation. This method has has to be called the first time after the dataTable is populated with its columns and before the dataTable gets rendered the first time.

My initial idea was to introduce a @FacesComponent, bind my columnToggler to this @FacesComponent and listen to certain JSF events, but for instance with this implementation the columns will only be updated on second call:

```
@FacesComponent(...)
public class ColumnTogglerComponent extends UINamingContainer

  @Override
  public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException  {
   // will be triggered for a javax.faces.event.PostRestoreStateEvent
   // to late !
  }
```

Where can I put the call to renderColumnsInDataTable? How do I trigger it?

BTW: I use PrimeFaces 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
@ListenerFor(systemEventClass=PostAddToViewEvent.class) 
public class ColumnTogglerComponent extends UINamingContainer { 
 ...
```

processEvent() will be called early enough.